# "above the fold" issue by google, without any css line

Tags: css, html

Im just started learning html5 & css.
For that im trying code my own page for training. Now i faced an issue calles "above the fold" i tryed solve this problem by search function here, but it seems my problem is a little bit other. Because in most cases here users give the advise to implement the critical css inline in html. the thing is i have just one line and thats already inline html (header). so i just can fix this when im deleting hole css also the referal link to my stylesheet. I just want to understand why i get this above the fold issue while i already inlined the one line css in my header. thank you for your answers!

**HTML Code :**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="de-AT">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="title" content="&#9654; Umzug nach Berlin | Ihr Umzugsprofi | Europaweite Umzüge -50%" />
        <meta name="description" content="Ihr verlässlicher Partner rund um Ihren Umzug nach Berlin. Mit Erfahrung aus über 15.000 Umzügen in ganz Europa. Jetzt unverbindlich anfragen. ✓ Schnell & Günstig ✓ Gratis Versicherung ✓ Günstige Preise ✓ EU-Umzug">
        <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="umzug nach berlin, umzug berlin, umzug, berlin, umzugsfirma, übersiedlung" />
     <title>Umzug nach Berlin - umzugdirekt.at</title>
        <style>
    .text {
     font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
```

Comment: You should refer this :https://css-tricks.com/authoring-critical-fold-css/

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. What is the problem? The only problem I see is that the text is mangled.